# Is there a way we can automate creating content type and data inside in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I am using strapi to create a default content type and some mock data for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

To create content type, you can use the command line and have a script to do that `strapi generate:api ...` and this will create content types.

Then if your application is running you can use the API of you content types to create data. And use Fakerjs to add random data.

Of use the [Query](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/queries.html#api-reference) system to add some data.